# Windows 10 Native Flash Player Repair / Reinstall

Tags: windows-10, flash-player, activex

Long story short:  A select amount of machines in my organization were deployed a package that installs a Windows 7 version of ActiveX Flash due to the machines being placed in the wrong collection (this started with version 21.0.0.242).  This installation gets flagged by our vulnerability scanners as it does not update automatically via Windows Update.  Attempts to uninstall the erroneous version breaks Internet Explorer's ability to utilize Flash in some cases.

Question:  Has anyone ever run into this issue and is there a method to completely revert, repair, or reinstall the native flash player installation and, perhaps more importantly, the registry keys associated with it?  After evaluating IE session using Process Monitor, it appears to want to use the erroneous version's OCX module, rather than the native Flash.OCX located in the %winsystem%\Macromed\Flash folder.

Answer (score 0):

You might try to run SFC or DISM to repair your system files. Open an Elevated command prompt and run:

`sfc /scannow`

It will repair any system files that are not correct. If that doesn't work, you can use DISM to check and restore the health of your installation. First, run:

`dism /Online /Cleanup-Image /ScanHealth`

If it finds anything, run:

`dism /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth`

Comment: Unfortunately, this did not work.  I believe I have may have found an alternative solution, but solution requires off topic discussion.  Will post in another thread.  Thank you.